# Error shown in checkbox function

Tags: php

I am writing function to display all checked values from database. Once I click to edit on specific product inside there are checkbox values which needs to be checked.

```
function emarketing_oprema(){
    $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
    $link->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM emarketing_oprema order by OpremaId asc ");

    while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
       data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]" value="'.$record["Oprema"];
       if(isset($record['checked'])) {//field in the database
         data+=' checked="checked';
       }
       data+='">'. $record["OpremaNaziv"] .'</br>';
    }
}
```

I get an error in line "`data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]`" `value="'.$record["Oprema"];"` and could not figure it out how to fix it.

I was wondering am I on good track. The goal is to according to partner Id get all values. I have finished that, the only step I need to do is to get checked values..

Comment: What error? In `php` `.` is the concatenation operator, not `+`.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Always use the $ sign before variable and for adding something to string us "." not +.

```
<?php
    function emarketing_oprema(){
        $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
        $link->set_charset("utf8");
        $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM emarketing_oprema order by OpremaId asc ");

        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
           $data="<input type='checkbox' name='oprema[]' value='{$record['Oprema']}' ";
           if(isset($record['checked'])) {//field in the database
             $data .=' checked="checked ';
           }
           $data .=' />'. $record["OpremaNaziv"] .'</br>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in php always use $ before your vars:

```
$data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]" value="'.$record["Oprema"];
if(isset($record['checked'])) {//field in the database
     $data+=' checked="checked';
   }
$data+='">'. $record["OpremaNaziv"] .'</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]" value="'.$record["Oprema"].'"';
   if(isset($record['checked'])) {//field in the database
     $data.=' checked="checked';
   }
   $data.='">'. $record["OpremaNaziv"] .'</br>';
}
```